# Getting images to float left and right of content and not take up vertical space

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on adding background images to a wordpress theme. I added the following code below the body tag:

```
<!-- Custom floating background  -->
<img id="left-girl" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/left-girl.png">
<img id="right-girl" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/right-girl.png">
```

I am trying to get them to float to the left and the right of the sites main content without effecting the vertical space.

Here is my CSS:

```
#left-girl {
float:left;
margin-left:5em;
}

#right-girl {
float:right;
margin-right:5em;
}
```

This is whay I get:

[image]
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Whoops! Forgot to tag as code.

Comment: Why did you not use `background-image` for this?

Comment: You may have to use the `clear:none` for the following element.

Comment: I tried adding clear:non to the following div but it did not work.

Comment: try positioning `absolute`.

Comment: @DavidTunnell that's because your webpage may have some crossed styles (styles override each other), try using the flag `!important` for a style you want to apply in any case, using clear should work, here is the fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mFgcb/4/ Also note that the center element should have width **small** enough to fit into the center space, otherwise it will be rendered below the floated elements.

Comment: If they are background images why not put them in the bg of the body?..No space required at all that way, no floats no positioning...simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/left-girl.png" /></div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="right"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/right-girl.png" /></div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#wrapper {padding-left:120px; padding-right:120px;} /*padding should be width of respective images plus what padding you want*/
#wrapper:after {content:''; display:block; clear:both; height:0; overflow:hidden;}
#wrapper > div {float:left;}
#wrapper > .left {width:100px; /*width of image*/ margin-left:-120px; /*minus amount of left padding*/}
#wrapper > .right {float:right; width:100px; /*width of image*/ margin-right:-120px; /*minus amount of right padding*/}
#wrapper > .main {width:100%;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gJ2hG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping text around images is easy. Just use float left / right, and add the desired dimensions to your images (width & height).

Please see this fiddle I created for you and let me know if it answeres your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/zQLzd/

HTML

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" class="left">
<div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus esse     laudantium         fugit voluptatibus quas cumque vero perspiciatis minima quae voluptatem eos illo aperiam alias odit voluptate asperiores natus cupiditate magnam.
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" class="right">
```

CSS

```
.left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.text {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```